# how to a detect my process has superuser privileges in windows os

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

how to a detect my process has superuser privileges in windows os.
for example i would like to detect if my ie explore is using superuser privilege my account is administrators groups or normal user groups

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to know if your process has an elevated token? Or do you want to know whether or not the user is in admin group? And why do you want to know? You say "my process" but then you talk about IE. Are you coding a BHO?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [IsUserAnAdmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776463%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.

**Edit:** Alternatively, based on the reading of that API it might be better to directly use [CheckTokenMembership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376389%28VS.85%29.aspx) since the future availability of IsUserAnAdmin seems to be in doubt; there is an example on that page.

Answer (score 0):

To get the groups info, you may use `GetUserName` and then [NetUserGetInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but by your question it wasn't evident if you are looking for such thing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VB6 solution to check if the current process is elevated; should be easy enough to translate to C++.

```
Public Function IsCurrentProcessElevated() As Boolean
    Dim lRet As Long, pAdministratorsGroup As Long
    Dim udtSidIdentifierAuthority As SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY

    udtSidIdentifierAuthority.Value(5) = 5  ' SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY

    lRet = AllocateAndInitializeSid(udtSidIdentifierAuthority, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID, DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, pAdministratorsGroup)
    If lRet <> 0 Then
        If CheckTokenMembership(0, pAdministratorsGroup, lRet) <> 0 Then    ' Use 0 to check the calling thread
            IsCurrentProcessElevated = (lRet <> 0)
        End If
        ' Note: This line was often crashing in Windows 7, fix was to change the API declare to recieve argument ByVal
        ' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913087/checktokenmembership-in-vb6-crashing-on-freesid-on-windows-7-and-windows-2008
        Call FreeSid(pAdministratorsGroup)
    End If
End Function
```