# Calls to the FreeSid() function crashes my MFC application on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

`FreeSid()` crashes frequently on Windows 7 in our MFC application. It has been working perfectly fine in Windows XP for years.

Does anyone know the workaround for this?

[Someone else had this same problem in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913087/checktokenmembership-in-vb6-crashing-on-freesid-on-windows-7-and-windows-2008), but it is not clear how to fix it in C++.

Comment: The problem the VB 6 person was having was that he had declared the function with the wrong signature. That's probably inapplicable here. Are you passing a valid pointer to the function? We'll need to see some code...

Comment: To expand on Cody's comment, just because it didn't crash in XP doesn't mean there isn't a problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, we will recheck with pointer usage and come back.

Comment: *We*? You and the C++ compiler?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to free a SID. If you get it from `ConvertStringSidToSid`, use `LocalFree`. If you get it from `AllocateAndInitializeSid`, use `FreeSid`. Mixing the two will give undefined results which may differ between Windows versions.

Comment: This problem was happening because of following user groups
SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$Machine2
SQLServerMSSQLServerADHelperUser$Machine2

SQLServerMSSQLUser$Machine2$SQLEXPRESS
SQLServerSQLAgentUser$Machine2$SQLEXPRESS

We got rid of these user groups and code started to work fine.

Thanks

Comment: @user1314356: your code is still broken, you've just hidden the problem by removing the circumstances that expose it.

Comment: Yes we have been facing so many problems while moving our code to Windows7 and VS 2010 that we are happy to have even a workaround